# Why am I getting `deleting from reference tables` even though I have disables foreign keys

Tags: mysql, delete-row, percona

So I am deleting records from a table by joining that table to another table.

I have disabled the foreign keys before I started running this statement.

So I have two tables A and B and I am deleting columns from table A using a join with column B to delete records that match on column `id` and one more criteria in where clause.

Here is the query

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

delete db.A from db.A join db.B USING(id) where name='xx';

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Why do I still get the following 'State' in mysql process list

> deleting from reference tables

Comment: The question doesn't make sense? Just trying to find out why no replies.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are "referencing a table" (db.A) in a multi table query (db.A and db.B).

If you don't specify a table on a "delete join", the query will not work, because mysql will not know which table you are trying to update.

Thereby you reference a table for delete.